# UIPageViewController of NavigationController->ViewController's starts 20 pixels too high on load, then moves down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

So I've searched and searched and searched for answers regarding this question, and I still cannot figure it out. I've done all of the typical "edgesforextendedlayout", disabling auto adjust scroll views on everything/nothing, unchecking "under top/bottom/opaque bars" and nothing works. I've narrowed it down to pretty much the iPhone 6/6S Plus. Doesn't happen on the iPhone 4S/5/6/6S and an assortment of iPads.

So I have a PageView (that is also one of the tabs on my tab bar controller) of 4 Navigation Controllers and their respective ViewControllers. Inside of the ViewControllers are graphs (iOSCharts). When I click on the "Graphs" tab on my tab bar controller, it goes to the PageView and displays the first graph, and it display fine. Then, only like 75% of the time, and on random graphs, it will start the view all the way at the top (under the status bar), and then a second later drop it down 20 pixels (basically a status bar's height) and display correctly. And after this, no matter where you go in the app/click/change etc, its fine. Its only on the first load.

I linked a picture as well (in the middle of switching pages).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUYzm.png

Comment: I am tempted to suggest Storyboard, since it won't require any of the `edgesforextendedlayout` dance and probably work out of the box.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect Storyboard is what I'm using actually

Comment: Great! You may want to remove all the code that tinkers with edges, extents, opaque bars, etc. A lot of it is transitional, legacy programmatic kludges. It all can be solved using the view controllers and `topLayoutGuide` and proper `UINavigationController` chains.

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I can try removing most of that. But I still would need a little bit of that for the page dots to show above the tab bar

Comment: Did you check log for conflicting `NSLayoutConstraints`? My experience with *AutoLayout* is that the less code you write, the better it works. Have you tried to replicate you layout in a fresh project, with 0 lines of code?

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I know I have some layout warnings and I'll look through those. And I'll try to rework something without any code and test. Any idea why its only happening on 6 Plus though?

Comment: Yes/no. Warnings and layout conflicts are solved at runtime. It is totally conceivable that the cleanup algorithm takes a different path on iPhone 6 Plus, because these conflicts may happen later or earlier in the parsing process. I've had apps crashing on iOS 7 because of conflicting constraints.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and nothing is working for me :(
Project that demonstrate the bug: https://github.com/augard/PageScrollingBug